# Transparent SelectionBackColor for DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In a Windows Forms DataGridView I'm trying to make the selected row have bold font and not change the background color.

For that matter I used the following code:

```
// This method is used to load the data into the grid
private void GridLoad()
{
    // Configures the Data Source

    Grid.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;

    Grid.ClearSelection();          
}

private void Grid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataGridView = Grid;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = dataGrid.Font;
    }

    if (dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        var selectedRow = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0];
        selectedRow.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(dataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }            
}
```

The code works, when I click one of the rows to select it, the font becomes bold, but there is one overlap.

The text gets duplicated, it seems the original text in regular font stays on background and the new text on bold appears on top slightly displaced to the right.

Why is it happening? Why this overlap is happening and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is in this line:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Remove it and then you will have no problem in rendering.

Don't set `SelectionBackColor` to `Color.Transparent`, if you want to have a If you don't want to have a transparent selection back color for cells, it's enough to set `SelectionBackColor` to the same value as `BackColor` of the cell.

A more suitable event for such purpose is [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView`. Using this event you can provide dynamic formatting for cells:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected)
    {
        e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = e.CellStyle.ForeColor;
        e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = e.CellStyle.BackColor;
    }
    else
    {
        e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This also works, it correctly makes the font of the selected row bold, but there's still the overlap issue. Do you have any guess of what it could be? Thanks again!

Comment: Check the edited answer, The main problem is in this line: `Grid.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;`. Remove it and then you will have no problem in rendering. If you don't want to have a `SelectionBackColor`, it's enough to set `SelectionBackColor` to the value of `BackColor` of the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the solution! Also, sorry for the delay in marking the answer as accepted, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

As I was also looking for not covering the original color's and I could not find any good answer, I made an extension for this to create a semi transparent look.
It stay's up-to-date if the background colors change and also works with selecting individual cells

You can use this extension like this

```
dataGridView1.EnableSemiTransparentSelection();
```

This will be the result

[image: Mixing the original backcolor with a selection color makes it look transparent]

First you need a colormixer, this will create the transparent effect if we use the original background color

```
    //Mix two colors
    //Example: Steps=10 & Position=4 makes Color2 mix 40% into Color1
    public static Color MixColor(Color Color1, Color Color2, int Steps, int Position)
    {
        if (Position <= 0 || Steps <= 1) { return Color1; }
        if (Position >= Steps) { return Color2; }
        return Color.FromArgb(
            Color1.R + ((Color2.R - Color1.R) / Steps * Position),
            Color1.G + ((Color2.G - Color1.G) / Steps * Position),
            Color1.B + ((Color2.B - Color1.B) / Steps * Position)
            );
    }
```

Second, making the extension

```
    //Mix SelectionBackColor
    public static void EnableSemiTransparentSelection(this DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        dataGridView.RowPrePaint += new DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventHandler(GridSemiTransparentSelection_RowPrePaint);
    }
    private static void GridSemiTransparentSelection_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Selected == false) { continue; }
            var bgColorCell = Color.White;
            if (cell.Style.BackColor != Color.Empty) { bgColorCell = cell.Style.BackColor; }
            else if (cell.InheritedStyle.BackColor != Color.Empty) { bgColorCell = cell.InheritedStyle.BackColor; }
            cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = MixColor(bgColorCell, Color.FromArgb(0,150,255), 10, 4);
        }
    }
```