# DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor not working smoothly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Just as title says, `DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor not working smoothly` and what i mean by that is i create form and inside load event i use this code:

```
using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter("SELECT BRDOK, DATUM, ZA_MAGACINID AS MAGACIN, KOMENTAR1 AS ODREDISTE, PRETVOREN_U_BRDOK_KOMERCIJALNO AS VEZA, FLAG FROM DOKUMENT WHERE VRDOK = 999", con))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        dataGridView1.Columns["BRDOK"].Width = 100;
        dataGridView1.Columns["DATUM"].Width = 100;
        dataGridView1.Columns["MAGACIN"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.Columns["ODREDISTE"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.Columns["VEZA"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.Columns["FLAG"].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

there as you can see i set `dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;`

and when i start my form i get this

[image]

As you can see, first row is white. It goes to transparent when i click on other row and back on it but first appearance is problem. What to do?

Comment: Does the grid have focus when it first starts? I haven't tried it, but IIRC, the DGV might have property set to hide selection when not focused which can throw a wrench in your coloring plan

Comment: @Vikhram No, it is not in focus. One of other buttons is.

Comment: Then you should either make sure the `Form.Show` event brings the DGV to focus by executing `dataGridView1.Focus()`. This should solve your issue. You can also do that by making sure the `DataGridView.TabIndex` is set to the lowest number on the current form (IMO a better approach). Or you can change the DGV property to reflect that you want to show selection on unfocused DGV, and if a style exists for unfocussed selectionbackground, then set that also to transparent

Comment: [Transparent SelectionBackColor for DataGridView Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38337849/3110834)

Comment: @Vikhram focusing it inside `Shown()` event didn't work but `dataGridView1.ClearSelection()` did

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using Transparent as your color.  Try using the same color as the grid itself:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
```

Comment: Cant, each row has different color depending on some data

Comment: @AleksaRistic You can try this in your form's constructor: `dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) => { dataGridView1.ClearSelection(); };`

Comment: I cleared selection in `Shown()` event with `dataGridView1.ClearSelection()` and it worked out.

Comment: @AleksaRistic What if the user clicks on a row?

Comment: It does stays transparent, just forecolor change